# TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to write dictionary contents to file and save.
I just got this message:
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'tuple'

```
#Creation of dictionary
final_dict = {}
final_dict['file_name']=d['filename'] 
final_dict1 = {} 
final_dict1['binary']=temp
final_dict1['type']=temp1

V10=((['file_name']),(['binary']),(['type']))
print(V10)
(['file_name'], ['binary'], ['type'])

outputfile = open('XXXXX.pptx', 'wb')
outputfile.write(base64.b64decode(V10))
outputfile.close()  
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 outputfile = open('XXXXX.pptx', 'wb')
----> 2 outputfile.write(base64.b64decode(V1))
      3 outputfile.close()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\base64.py:80, in b64decode(s, altchars, validate)
     65 def b64decode(s, altchars=None, validate=False):
     66     """Decode the Base64 encoded bytes-like object or ASCII string s.
     67 
     68     Optional altchars must be a bytes-like object or ASCII string of length 2
   (...)
     78     in the input result in a binascii.Error.
     79     """
---> 80     s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
     81     if altchars is not None:
     82         altchars = _bytes_from_decode_data(altchars)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\base64.py:45, in _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
     43     return memoryview(s).tobytes()
     44 except TypeError:
---> 45     raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
     46                     "string, not %r" % s.__class__.__name__) from None

TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'tuple'
```

Note: What I expect to write to the variable:

{'file_name': 'ABCDERFROOEKWWKE.pptx'} {'binary': 'UEsXAAIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAACclAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLFFFFBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...

Comment: V10 is a tuple, but base64 is for strings. It makes no sense to say you want to base64 decode a tuple

Comment: Why do you expect it to write UEsXAAIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAACclAAATAA...? Where does that string come from?

Comment: @user253751, when i print the dictionary (print(final_dict, final_dict1)) i get this output:{'file_name': 'ABCDERFROOEKWWKE.pptx'} {'binary': 'UEsXAAIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAACclAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLFFFFBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA That's what I want you to write to the file.

Comment: so then why did you write `base64.b64decode(V10)`?

Comment: I missed copying the "0" here. I've run the code again, and I get the same message :(

Comment: if `base64.b64decode(V10)` **isn't** what you want the computer to put in the file, then why did you tell the computer to put that in the file?

Comment: With this function, I want to do decode with base64 function and then save to document.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). You want to use base64 to save a tuple, but that really isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Women_it_2022 but `V10` isn't the thing you want to decode, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be written to a file, objects first need to be converted to `str` or `bytes` object depending on the writing mode
(see [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)):

```
with open(file_name, "w") as file:
    file.write(str( my_object ))
```

If you want to encode (not decode) it in base64 just call `b64encode` on `str(my_object).encode()` in binary mode

If instead, you want to decode the values of your dictionary before writing it, then just construct a new dictionary `{k: b64decode(v) for k, v in old_dict.items()}`

Also, since you used json as a tag, have a look at `json.dump` ([Saving structured data with json](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json))